# Can I tell my terminal emulator to push URLs to private mode?

Tags: firefox, gnome-terminal, mutt, privacy

I'm using `neomutt` as my mail client, in Gnome Terminal 3.28.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. I'd like to open inline URLs in a Firefox Private Window by default -- right now they open a new tab in an existing, non-Private Window.

I can do this in my mailcap with the [-private-window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-private-toggle) flag, but that won't work for just selecting "open link" from the gnome-terminal context menu.

There's a Mozilla support thread from an OSX user asking how to [do this globally](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1119073) and the answer appears to be that you can't, but I'm on Ubuntu and tbh only need this to work from `neomutt` running in a terminal.

Comment: `but that won't work for just selecting "open link" from my context menu.` How are you doing this exactly? Right-clicking on the link in the terminal? If so, then it's the terminal emulator's context menu, and nothing to do with neomutt.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the context menu by right-clicking on the URL in my terminal. Will edit the question.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is that "you can't", at least just for neomutt and Gnome terminal. It [looks like](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42344/how-do-i-change-the-browser-that-gnome-terminal-opens-links-with) Gnome Terminal just uses the "default" web browser setting. You could possibly hack this to always use private windows, but then *every single* link (from all programs that use the default) would be opened in a private window.